# Solutions of Differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation,$$y'' - y = 0,$$

If $y_{1} = Ae^{x}$ and $y_{2} = Be^{-x}$ are linearly independent solutions. Prove that $\alpha y_{1} + \beta y_{2}$ is also a solution of the differential equation.

What would I do to rigorously prove this?

Comment: Calculate its second derivative and then show the difference of the function and this derivative is $0$.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought but I was wondering if there was any proof of the logic behind the statement.

Comment: No. There's nothing to it other than what "a solution of the differential equation" means.

Comment: Ok and I assume if we rephrase the statement to "if $y_{1}=Ae^{x}$ and $y_{2} = Be^{-x}$ are linearly independent solutions, then the family of functions $y = \alpha e^{x} + \beta e^{-x}$ are also solutions", your statement still holds?

Comment: Already to make that statement you have to know that the solutions form a linear space. What is demanded to be shown is that for homogenous linear differential equations, linear combinations of solutions are again solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could substitute into the differential equation as suggested in the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687164/solutions-of-differential-equations/687213#comment1441249_687164). It's also possible to show it without doing any differentiation of $Ae^x$ and $Be^{-x}$. With $y=\alpha y_1+ \beta y_2$:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx^2}(y) - y
&= \frac{d}{dx^2}\left(  \alpha y_1 + \beta y_2  \right) - (\alpha y_1 + \beta y_2) \\
&= \alpha y_1'' -  \alpha y_1 + \beta y_2'' - \beta y_2\\
&= \alpha (y_1'' -  y_1) + \beta (y_2'' -  y_2)\\
&= \alpha\times0 + \beta\times0 = 0
\end{align}$$
The last line follows because $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions of the differential equation.

This applies for *any* $y_1$, $y_2$ and follows from the linearity (and homogeneity) of the differential equation.

Comment: +1 for answer. Just change your definition of y in the opening paragraph to reflect that it was a general linear combination as you used in the rest of the derivation :).

Comment: @Chinny84 thankyou kindly